# Cheetah class that extends animals. Java

Tags: java

The Cheetah extension won't run. It gives all the lion output. But the cheetah won't output. It runs fine as it is with no errors, it just bypasses the cheetah inheritance and won't output it.

Modify the existing Animal.java file for this task.

- Create a class called ‘Cheetah’ that:
- Inherits from the Animal class.
- Makes use of at least one static field which needs to have a static setter and getter.
- Contains a constructor.
- Contains a toString() method.
- Has an array as one of it’s fields.
- Create an application class, and within it create a Cheetah object and print out with the main method.

All of it is there the cheetah just won't run.

```
    public class Animal {
    private int numTeeth = 0;
    private boolean spots = false;
    private int weight = 0;

    public Animal(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight){
        this.setNumTeeth(numTeeth);
        this.setSpots(spots);
        this.setWeight(weight);
    }

    public int getNumTeeth(){
        return numTeeth;
    }

    public void setNumTeeth(int numTeeth) {
        this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
    }

    public boolean getSpots() {
        return spots;
    }

    public void setSpots(boolean spots) {
        this.spots = spots;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Lion lion = new Lion(30, false, 80);
        System.out.println(lion);
    }

    public static void main1(String[] args){
        Cheetah cheetah = new Cheetah(30, true, 45);
        System.out.println(cheetah);
    }

}
```

Lion Class

```
 class Lion extends Animal {
    String type = "";

    public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
        super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
        type(weight);
    }
    public String type(int weight){
        super.setWeight(weight);
        if(weight <= 80){
            type = "Cub"; 
        }
        else if(weight <= 120){
            type = "Female";
        }
        else{
            type = "Male";
        }
        return type;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        String output = "Number of Teeth: " + getNumTeeth(); 
        output += "\nDoes it have spots?: " + getSpots();
        output += "\nHow much does it weigh: " + getWeight();
        output += "\nType of Lion: " + type;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Cheetah class:

```
 class Cheetah extends Animal {         

        public Cheetah(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
            super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
        }

        public String toString(String cheetah) { 
            String output = "Number of Teeth: " + getNumTeeth(); 
            output += "\nDoes it have spots?: " + getSpots();
            output += "\nHow much does it weigh: " + getWeight();
            output += "\nCheetah";
            return output;
 }
 }
```

Comment: The JVM will run the `main(String[] args)` method of the class. Something called different like `main1(String[] args)` will not be automatically run.

Comment: what do you mean "won't run"? some of your code makes very little sense, like deciding gender on weight. Are you sure that's how you should look at it?

Comment: `toString(String cheetah)` is an overload, not override. Remove the parameter. And don't use `main1`, it's recognized as a simple method, not  `main`.

Comment: @Stultuske yes the gender thing is supposed to be like that. Example male lion 120 kg because he is bigger than female of 80kg etc.

Comment: bit of an odd reasoning, there are always exceptions, I'll just assume it was part of the assignment like that? But the other responses are right, the entrypoint has a fixed signature, so main1 will indeed not be recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove main1 method from your code and edit your main method like this :

`public static void main(String[] args){Lion lion = new Lion(30, false, 80);System.out.println(lion);Cheetah cheetah = new Cheetah(30, true, 45);System.out.println(cheetah);
}`

Comment: Number of Teeth: 30
Does it have spots?: false
How much does it weigh: 80
Type of Lion: Cub
Cheetah@7a81197d thats the new output... i need the cheetah output same as the lion one just without the the whole weight classification types.

Comment: You can change the input value as per your need. You can pass as input param as passed in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote two `main` functions with different names. However, Java will always run the so-called `main()` function.